# Translate image but container within container

Tags: javascript, vue.js

i'm trying to create a Vue component which lets the user click and drag an image when it's scaled up. I want the image to be moved around, however the the image doesn't currently stay within the container properly, it's close, but can't figure out why it still goes out of from slightly and then gets stuck.

I also need to keep it in frame when you zoom back out.

I can't figure out the calculations to do this, can someone give me a hand? This is what I have so far however as you can see it isn't quite right.

Double click or scroll to zoom in to start the click and drag function.

## Edit

Updated my code with an attempt, which in theory should work, and it kind of does. However it appears that when I move my mouse 1 pixel it works, then the next pixel it doesn't. It seems that the data and rendering isn't in sync, so the code moves the updates the translation but then within the next pixel the `getBoundingClientRect` is updated which then correctly updates it again moving it back so the image doesn't go out of the container...

I thought adding `requestAnimationFrame` would fix the issue, but it hasn't.

```js
Vue.component('draggable', {
  data: function() {
    return {
      loading: true,
      
      zoomLevels: [1, 1.5, 2, 2.5, 3],
      zoomLevel: 1,

      lastX: 0,
      lastY: 0,

      touchX: 0,
      touchY: 0,

      startX: 0,
      startY: 0,

      translateX: 0,
      translateY: 0,

      isMoving: false,
      isDragging: false
    }
  },
  methods: {
    handleDoubleClick() {
      let index = this.zoomLevels.indexOf(this.zoomLevel) + 1;
      if (this.zoomLevels[index] === undefined) {
        index = 0;
      }
      this.zoomLevel = this.zoomLevels[index];
    },
    handleWheel($event) {
      $event.preventDefault();

      this.zoomLevel += $event.deltaY * -0.01;

      if (this.zoomLevel < 1) {
        this.zoomLevel = 1;
      }

      let maxZoom = this.zoomLevels[this.zoomLevels.length - 1];

      this.zoomLevel = Math.min(Math.max(.125, this.zoomLevel), maxZoom);

    },
    handleMouseDown($event) {
      if ($event.button !== 0) {
        return;
      }
      this.isDragging = true;
      this.isMoving = true;

      this.startX = $event.pageX;
      this.startY = $event.pageY;
    },
    handleMouseUp($event) {
      if ($event.button !== 0) {
        return;
      }
      this.isMoving = false;
    },
    handleMouseMove($event) {
            if ($event.button !== 0) {
                return;
            }
            if (this.isMoving && this.isDragging) {
                if (this.zoomLevel !== 1) {

                    let parentBounding = $event.target.parentNode.getBoundingClientRect();
                    let clientBounding = $event.target.getBoundingClientRect();

                    window.requestAnimationFrame(() => this.handleTranslate(
                        { x: $event.pageX, y: $event.pageY },
                        { parent: parentBounding, client: clientBounding }
                    ));
                    return;
                }
                this.handleMovement({ x: $event.pageX, y: $event.pageY }, $event);
            }
        },
    handleTranslate(positions, bounding) {
            let offsetX = (Math.floor(bounding.parent.left) - Math.floor(bounding.client.left));
            if (offsetX >= 0) {
                offsetX = 0;
            }
            this.translateX = Math.floor((positions.x - this.startX) + Math.floor(offsetX));

            if ((Math.floor(bounding.parent.top) - Math.floor(bounding.client.top)) > 0) {
                this.translateY = Math.floor((positions.y - this.startY));
            }
        },
  },
  computed: {
    translate: function() {
      return `translateX(${this.translateX}px) translateY(${this.translateY}px)`;
    }
  },
  template: '#template'
});

this.app = new Vue({}).$mount('#app');
```

```css
.container {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: black;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.container img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <draggable></draggable>
</div>

<script type="text/x-template" id="template">
  <div class="container">
    <img draggable="false" 
      @mouseup="handleMouseUp" 
      @mousedown="handleMouseDown" 
      @mousemove="handleMouseMove" 
      @dblclick="handleDoubleClick" 
      @wheel="handleWheel" 
      src="https://cdn2.yamaha-motor.eu/prod/product-assets/2020/YZF1000R1/2020-Yamaha-YZF1000R1-EU-Icon_Blue-Static-001-03.jpg"
      :style="{ transform: `scale(${zoomLevel}) ${translate}` } ">
    </div> 
</script>
```